# Redirecting to dev/null

Tags: linux, standard-error

Why can't I redirect standard error to /dev/null?

```
xxx:xxx 84> find / -name trans.log 2> /dev/null
```

Outputs

> find: paths must precede expression: 2

Comment: I do not reproduce the error. Some space characters in your command might be other invisible characters. Please make a hex dump, as follows : echo "<your command>" | hexdump -C

Comment: Are you using the "bash" shell? Check whether "ps $$" contains "bash". (Notably, csh does not support the "2>" syntax.)

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is;
The greater-thans (>) in commands like these redirect the program’s output somewhere. In this case, something is being redirected into /dev/null, and something is being redirected into &1

```
xxx:xxx 84> find / -name trans.log >/dev/null 2>&1
```

If you don't specify a number then the standard output stream is assumed but you can also redirect errors

```
> file redirects stdout to file
1> file redirects stdout to file
2> file redirects stderr to file
&> file redirects stdout and stderr to file
```

`/dev/null` is the null device it takes any input you want and throws it away. It can be used to suppress any output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your shell doesn't interpret "2>" as a shell expression, but it passes this argument to the `find` command:

> find: paths must precede expression: 2

The "2" here seems to be analyzed by `find` as an expression.

I cannot reproduce here with my shell, but try to remove the space between `2>` and `/dev/null`, so it is `2>/dev/null`.